# Function that checks if values in a list are the same as specific value lists in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I want to make a function that takes a list of strings and a dictionary as inputs. If any strings in the list match a set of values in the dictionary, they should return a key corresponding to those values.

An example input would look something like `available_dishes(ingredients, recipes)`. Where

```
ingredients = ['Fish','Rice','Eggs','Ketchup']
recipes = {'Sushi':['Fish','Rice','Seaweed'],'Grilled_Fish':['Fish'],'Omurice':['Eggs','Rice','Ketchup']}
```

Because the list only has the necessary ingredients for grilled fish and omurice, this would return the output: `['Grilled_Fish','Omurice']`. Specifically, the results should appear in the order that the keys appear in the dictionary.

**What I'm Trying**

In my attempt, I have isolated one of the lists in the list of dictionary values. I tried focusing on one list so that I might understand how the rest of them might function. What I’ve made isn’t necessarily a function but a group of variables I wanted to try interpreting.

```
recipe_ingredients = list(recipes.values())

for i in ingredients:
    if i in recipe_ingredients[0]:
        print(i)
```

Unfortunately, for now, my knowledge of python is limited so this only returns the matching ingredients between the two lists: `Fish Rice`. **I’m still somewhat inexperienced with for loops, so I’d like to see how this could be done using them as well as if statements.** **If possible, could this be done without the use of list comprehension?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `all()` to check if recipe has **all** available ingredients:

```py
ingredients = ["Fish", "Rice", "Eggs", "Ketchup"]
recipes = {
    "Sushi": ["Fish", "Rice", "Seaweed"],
    "Grilled_Fish": ["Fish"],
    "Omurice": ["Eggs", "Rice", "Ketchup"],
}

out = [k for k, v in recipes.items() if all(i in ingredients for i in v)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['Grilled_Fish','Omurice']
```

---

Without list-comprehension:

```py
out = []
for k, v in recipes.items():
    if all(i in ingredients for i in v):
        out.append(k)

print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sets are your friends. They are an unordered collection of unique items, like the ingredients of a recipe. First I have turned your lists into sets:

```
my_ingredients = {'Fish', 'Rice', 'Eggs', 'Ketchup'}
recipes = {'Sushi': {'Fish', 'Rice', 'Seaweed'},'Grilled_Fish': {'Fish'}, 'Omurice': {'Eggs',  'Rice', 'Ketchup'}}
```

You can then check that the ingredients of a recipe are a subset of your ingredients. Here it is how to use that condition in a list comprehension:

```
>>> [food for food, ingredients in recipes.items() if ingredients.issubset(my_ingredients)]
['Grilled_Fish', 'Omurice']
```